# What is the best way to populate fields from a SharePoint List?

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, sharepoint-designer

I am looking to populate an HTML form(on my SharePoint site) with information from a SharePoint List. The context behind this is that events are created with certain fields(title, description, date/times), then another page should be displaying this event info and allow people to pick a time they desire. I am looking to do this field population through JavaScript or SharePoint Designer? If that is possible(i'm new to SharePoint, so questions may sound basic.)

Any help is appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: you can using Javascript object model or SharePoint REST API. All you need is to pass the id of created event in querystring while redirecting to HTML form (through button click or something) then based on id from query string, use SharePoint REST API get item endpoint or JSOM to retrieve event info and fill relevant form fields

Comment: okay that makes sense, do you have any reference links where to start code wise? Just to get going.

Comment: you would write html for your target page like you do for normal web pages, to redirect to that page you can use standard javascript e.g. `window.location.href = "yourSPpage.aspx?itemId=[sharepoint-item-id]"`, once redirected to your sharepoint page you can use https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/hh185007(v%3Doffice.14) (with minor modifications), to get list item details based on id, once you get the details you can populate html controls in `success` handler. you can use Content editor webpart on your target page, to insert your HTML and JS

Comment: *Continued - *, you would create a SharePoint Page as well where you will put your HTML and JavaScript in a Content Editor webpart. You will redirect to this SharePoint page (along with id in query string)

Comment: ah okay, that is some good info! thanks so much!